# Common entries among multiple columns

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data table like

```
library(data.table)
df = data.table("a" = c('aa (1)', 'bb (2)', 'cc (3)'), 
                "b" = c('aa (2)', 'bb (2)', 'dd (3)'), 
                "c" = c('dd (3)', 'aa (1)', 'ff (3)'))
       a      b      c
1: aa (1) aa (2) dd (3)
2: bb (2) bb (2) aa (1)
3: cc (3) dd (3) ff (3)
```

I want to find common elements between column "a" and others and only the characters, not the numbers
so the result would be

```
aa and bb are common in a and b column 
aa is common between column a and c.
```

How can I do that.

I tried to use intersect, but don't know how efficiently i would get rid of the numbers.

Comment: Can you post the expected output, please? The explanation is not very clear.

Comment: I just edited the question

Comment: I'm not sure what's your desired output, but you could also try `melt(df, measure = names(df))[, toString(variable), by = sub(" \\(.*", "", value)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First remove the junk at the end of each element and then intersect each column with `a`.  That will give a second column `V2` as a list of vectors and a third column `V3` as character strings:

```
df[, lapply(.SD, sub, pattern = "[ (].*", replacement = "")][, 
  .(names(df)[-1], sapply(.SD, intersect, a)), .SDcols = -1][,
  .(V1, V2, V3 = sapply(V2, toString))]
```

giving:

```
   V1    V2     V3
1:  b aa,bb aa, bb
2:  c    aa     aa
```

or if you prefer long form then use the following which is the same as above except the last line:

```
df[, lapply(.SD, sub, pattern = "[ (].*", replacement = "")][, 
       .(names(df)[-1], sapply(.SD, intersect, a)), .SDcols = -1][,
       lapply(.SD, unlist), by = V1]
```

giving:

```
   V1 V2
1:  b aa
2:  b bb
3:  c aa
```